# My Laravel Website is redirecting all post request to index page

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-6

Having Problem with **POST Request**

All the get routes are working fine.

Post route when submiting any form it gets updated in DB and then redirected to homepage but where I go back to previous link. I see that I am having all the success and errors on that page before getting redirected to homepage.

**My POST Route:**

`Route::post('/update-faq', 'FaqController@update')->name('admin.faq.update');`

**My Controller Function:**

```
public function index(){
        $all_faqs = Faq::all();
        return view('backend.pages.faqs')->with(['all_faqs' => $all_faqs]);
    }
public function update(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'status' => 'nullable|string|max:191',
        ]);

        Faq::find($request->id)->update([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'status' => $request->status,
            'is_open' => !empty($request->is_open) ? 'on' : '',
        ]);

        return redirect()->back()->with(['msg' => 'Faq Updated...','type' => 'success']);
    }
```

**My View:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="faq_item_edit_modal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">{{ 'Edit Faq Item' }}</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>×</span></button>
                </div>
                <form action="{{ route('admin.faq.update') }}" id="faq_edit_modal_form" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                    method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="faq_id" value="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="edit_title">{{ 'Title' }}</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit_title" name="title"
                                placeholder="{{ 'Title' }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="edit_is_open">{{ 'Is Open' }}</label>
                            <label class="switch">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="is_open" id="edit_is_open">
                                <span class="slider"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="edit_description">{{ 'Description' }}</label>
                            <textarea name="description" id="edit_description" cols="30" rows="10"
                                class="form-control max-height-150" placeholder="{{ 'Description' }}"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="edit_status">{{ 'Status' }}</label>
                            <select name="status" id="edit_status" class="form-control">
                                <option value="publish">{{ 'Publish' }}</option>
                                <option value="draft">{{ 'Draft' }}</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">{{ 'Close' }}</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ 'Save Changes' }}</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

            $(document).on('click', '.faq_edit_btn', function() {
                var el = $(this);
                var id = el.data('id');
                var title = el.data('title');
                var form = $('#faq_edit_modal_form');
                form.find('#faq_id').val(id);
                form.find('#edit_title').val(title);
                form.find('#edit_description').val(el.data('description'));
                form.find('#edit_status option[value="' + el.data('status') + '"]').attr('selected', true);
                if (el.data('is_open') != '') {
                    form.find('#edit_is_open').attr('checked', true);
                } else {
                    form.find('#edit_is_open').attr('checked', false);
                }
            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: where are you showing the success message

Comment: after successful update of data in DB

Comment: Please view this link you will understand it better.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P0Qh5bzvymm7P49ER4fslFbi5QQgObmb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your help got the issue solved there was an issue with .htaccess file.